Referring to Avro Schemas in another Avro Schema
I have the following 3 Avro schemas:

user.avsc:
{
  "name": "User",
  "namespace": "my.domain.kafka.ap",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "userId",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "logicalType": "uuid"
      }
    }
  ]
}


user-create.avsc:
{
    "name": "UserCreate",
    "namespace": "my.domain.kafka.api",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "timestamp",
            "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "logicalType": "uuid"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "user",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "my.domain.kafka.api.User"
            ],
            "default": null
        }
    ]
}


user-deactivate.avsc:
{
    "name": "UserDeactivate",
    "namespace": "my.domain.kafka.api",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "timestamp",
            "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "logicalType": "uuid"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "user",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "my.domain.kafka.api.User"
            ],
            "default": null
        }
    ]
}



As can be seen, the type my.domain.kafka.api.User is referenced in the other two schemas. For generation of schemas' DTOs I use avro-tool-1.9.1.jar:
java -jar avro-tool-1.9.1.jar compile schema user.avsc user-create.avsc user-deactivate.avsc

This command compiles 3 Files without any issues. The same can also be achieved with the maven plugin org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin by providing the sourceDirectory to the schemas.
The problem starts with the Kafka Topology Builder. As a configuration there is following YAML file defined:
    projects:
      - name: "my-project"
        ...
        topics:
          - name: "my-topic"
            subject.name.strategy: "TopicRecordNameStrategy"
            schemas:
              - value.schema.file: "../schemas/user.avsc"
                value.record.type: "my.domain.kafka.api.User"
              - value.schema.file: "../schemas/user-create.avsc"
                value.record.type: "my.domain.kafka.api.UserCreate"
              - value.schema.file: "../schemas/user-deactivate.avsc"
                value.record.type: "my.domain.kafka.api.UserDeactivate"
            config:
              ...

However, Kafka Topology Builder cannot find my.domain.kafka.api.User by compilation of user-create.avsc or user-deactivate.avsc. Following exceptions occurs:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Undefined name: "my.domain.kafka.api.User"

Looks like the Kafka Topology Builder takes one schema by one and tries to compile, not using the whole list of schemas in defined order as expected. Is there any trick I forgot to define in YAML file or the Builder does not support that at all?
One workaround would be to define specific "User" on every Schema, but this is really not good.

Maybe the following syntax of AVRO Schemas should be used instead? https://akhq.io/docs/configuration/schema-registry/schema-references.html
